# Transfer value from one number to another up to max pythonically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to "transfer value" between two variables up to a maximum value. For example, if I start with `x=5`, `y=3`, `max=7`, I would end with `x=7`, `y=1`, `max=7`. This seems like there would be a short/pythonic way to do it. What would be the shortest way to do in in python?

I did the following:

```
sum = x+y
return_list = []
if sum > max:
  return [max, sum-max]
else:
  return [sum, 0]
```

I realize I can change the last 4 lines to `return [max, sum-max] if sum > max else return [sum, 0]`, but I presume there may be a 1 line solution.

Comment: What have you tried, and why do you think it can be made shorter?

Comment: @ScottHunter - I'm trying to learn the "shortforms" in Python. Am just starting (from C/Java) so I've just typed out the entire `x+y-max / max(x+y, max)`. There's usually a shorter way to do things in python, so I guess I don't know if it's possible

Comment: Please edit your attempt into your question.

Comment: @Prune - Don't think it's of much help, but updated.

Comment: Read the posting guidelines: it shows that you made a valid attempt.  Without this, your question falls into the category of "Give me the best code; I'm not going to bother."  As you saw in the first few minutes, such questions get down-voted and closed.  I hope those people come back to see the improvement.

Comment: What should x=9, y=5, max=7 result in, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I extract these lines from "The Zen of Python":

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Flat is better than nested.
Readability counts.
```

Yes, you *could* do this as a one-liner, but you would have repeat some pre-computations, or wrap it all into a `lambda` or `with` block.  We can use tuple assignment and the ternary operator to make this more Pythonic.

```
def transfer(x, y, max):
    sum = x+y
    return (max, sum - max) if sum > max else (sum, 0)
```

If you remove the pre-computation, it becomes

```
    return (max, x+y - max) if x+y> max else (x+y, 0)
```

The triplication is harder to read and more prone to error.  Don't go there.

Comment: Thanks for your reference of [PEP 20 - The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)!